# body image positioning with body

Tags: php, html, css

I just finished designing by website and now I am trying to layout the entire body in one whole piece rather than tiles continually repeating itself. May I ask how would I do this?

I am not sure if i make sense, but like a wall paper that is stretching out rather then 30 little tiles repeating itself

this is my code

```
HTML and the CSS

*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;

}

body {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6TXzo5k9VRo8f0KY4P5UQECoegTmNsEcYpO2gNIuXxAN6CwBwEw')
}
```

and the html

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

    </head>
    <body>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `background-size`. There are two options:

Option 1) **cover** will remain proportional -- Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jUcL9/4/ (drag the handles between panes to change the width/height of the preview pane)

```
body { 
    background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6TXzo5k9VRo8f0KY4P5UQECoegTmNsEcYpO2gNIuXxAN6CwBwEw') no-repeat center top fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If you don't want the background to remain at the top, you would use `center center` instead of `center top` -- Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jUcL9/

Option 2) **100% 100%;** will distort to fit -- Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jUcL9/1/

```
body { 
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6TXzo5k9VRo8f0KY4P5UQECoegTmNsEcYpO2gNIuXxAN6CwBwEw') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Background Size and make it not repeat.

Here are some css properties to add to the body:

```
background-size:100px 100px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

You will need to adjust to the proper size.

Answer (score 0):

try inserting this on your css file:

```
html { 
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6TXzo5k9VRo8f0KY4P5UQECoegTmNsEcYpO2gNIuXxAN6CwBwEw") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```